# How to convert Any? to Data in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert from type `Any?` to `Data`.

something like this

```
func getItem(item:Any?) {
    let data = convertToData(item)
}
```

Comment: you just need to do `if let data = item as? Data {}`

Comment: How do you call `getItem(item:)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
func getItem(item:Any?) {
    if let data = item as? Data {
      // do your thing
    }else {
      // not convertible to Data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert `Any?` to data because `Any?` does not have a known type. It's literally *any* type at all (or nil, since you have an optional `Any`. you can use a conditional cast to try to cast your value to data, but it may fail:

```
func getItem(item:Any?) {
    guard let data = Data(item) else {
        return
    }
}
```